# Creating a do list using javascript ( How to delete the function by just clicking on the list element?)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am planning to create a simple to-do list to teach my students( I am also very new to JS)

```
function createlist() {
  let x = document.forms["todo"]["thing"].value;
  var head = document.createElement("li");
  head.innerText = x;
  head.style.color = "red";
  head.setAttribute("id", "listid");
  document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(head);
}
```

I want the list elements to be deleted when I click on them!
How do I dynamically create an event and link it to the list element created?

Answer (score 1):

Attach [a single event listener to the list element](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) to catch events from your list elements as they "bubble up" the DOM, and then add a class to the clicked item that sets its display to `none`.

```js
const list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick(e) {
  e.target.classList.add('deleted');
}
```

```css
.deleted { display: none; }
li:hover { cursor: pointer; color: blue; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```